# Sed replacement Argument list too long

Tags: bash, sed, base64

Yo, I'm trying to replace some strings with a value. This is my script.

```
declare -a imagesBase64=($LINE)
for val in ${imagesBase64[@]}; do
  sed -i "s|$val|$IMAGE_URL_S3|g" /path/to/file.html
  rm /path/to/file/$IMAGE
done
```

What is done here is to look up the base64 image value and change it to the value of the URL of the image uploaded to AWS S3. This was already stated but is irrelevant to the problem.

Where $LINE is each line in base64 of the file that iterates in a Do While that does a few things. And well, $IMAGE_URL_S3 means the image url in AWS S3.

This works without problems when an image is small or medium, and its base64 value is not very long. However, when it is a large image, or rather, when a base64 image has too many strings, the following message appears.

```
./myscript.sh: line 26: /bin/sed: Argument list too long
```

How can I replace it?

Comment: Check here for solutions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284170/replace-a-long-string-with-the-sed-command-argument-list-too-long-error

Comment: Thank you. I checked the query and did it on my end, but the message no longer appears and does not replace the file or does not run the sed command.